# Rotating images makes ui slow

Tags: android, image, animation, rotation

i'm trying to implement kind of speedometer. i'm getting informations about rounds per minute, boost and load of an engine over bluetooth and i try to display them on the screen witch 3 arrows witch should point in the right direktion. i tried to use a rotate animation evry time i get data(10-100ms) to setup the arrows. but that makes my ui extremly slow. 500ms to react on a buttonclick. Doese someone know how to make it work better?

source code:

```
public void setTacho()
{


//rotate Tachonadel
Rpmcurrentdegree=Rpmcurrentdegree+Rpmdegree;
Rpmdegree=((rpms-lastrpm)*RPMtoDegree);

RpmAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)Rpmcurrentdegree, (float)Rpmdegree,       ivNadel.getWidth()/2, ivNadel.getHeight()/2);
RpmAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
RpmAnim.setFillAfter(true);
ivNadel.setAnimation(RpmAnim);
RpmAnim.start();


//rotate Boostbalken
currentBoostDegree=currentBoostDegree+BoostDegree;
BoostDegree=(boost-lastBoost)*BOOSTtoDegree;

//rotate Loadbalken
currentLoadDegree=currentLoadDegree+LoadDegree;
LoadDegree=(load-lastLoad)*LOADtoDegree;


BoostAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)-currentBoostDegree, (float)-BoostDegree,     ivBoost.getWidth()/2, ivBoost.getHeight()/2);
BoostAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
BoostAnim.setFillAfter(true);
ivBoost.setAnimation(BoostAnim);
BoostAnim.start();

LoadAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)currentLoadDegree, (float)LoadDegree,     ivLoad.getWidth()/2, ivLoad.getHeight()/2);
LoadAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
LoadAnim.setFillAfter(true);
ivLoad.setAnimation(LoadAnim);
LoadAnim.start();

}
```

when i try to make the rotation only if the values have changed then it works only while they are changing but if they aren't the arrows jump back to the zero position. isnt setfillafter to tell the image that it should hold the new position?

code:

```
public void setTacho()

{
//rotate Tachonadel
Rpmcurrentdegree=Rpmcurrentdegree+Rpmdegree;
Rpmdegree=((rpms-lastrpm)*RPMtoDegree);


if(Rpmdegree!=0)
{
RpmAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)Rpmcurrentdegree, (float)Rpmdegree,     ivNadel.getWidth()/2, ivNadel.getHeight()/2);
RpmAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
RpmAnim.setFillAfter(true);
ivNadel.setAnimation(RpmAnim);
RpmAnim.start();
}

//rotate Boostbalken
currentBoostDegree=currentBoostDegree+BoostDegree;
BoostDegree=(boost-lastBoost)*BOOSTtoDegree;
//rotate Loadbalken
currentLoadDegree=currentLoadDegree+LoadDegree;
LoadDegree=(load-lastLoad)*LOADtoDegree;

if(BoostDegree!=0)
{
BoostAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)-currentBoostDegree, (float)-BoostDegree,     ivBoost.getWidth()/2, ivBoost.getHeight()/2);
BoostAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
BoostAnim.setFillAfter(true);
ivBoost.setAnimation(BoostAnim);
BoostAnim.start();
}




if(LoadDegree!=0)
{
LoadAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)currentLoadDegree, (float)LoadDegree,     ivLoad.getWidth()/2, ivLoad.getHeight()/2);
LoadAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
LoadAnim.setFillAfter(true);
ivLoad.setAnimation(LoadAnim);
LoadAnim.start();
}
}
```

i don't get it =(

thx 4 help

EDIT:

part of the bluetooth Thread that calls the callback

```
while (run) {
                try {

                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    if (connection.btCallback != null)
                    {
                            connection.btCallback.getData(buffer,bytes);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    break;
                }
```

the callback methode of the bluetooth thread:

```
public void getData(byte[] bytes, int len)
        {
           setTacho(); 
        }
```

Comment: Are you running the rotation code on a separate thread or UI thread?

Comment: but i tried it in both and doesn't change anything

Comment: can you include the thread part too?

Comment: well thats a lot^^ this funktion is called by the Callback method of the bluetooth thread. so aktually it is implemented in the main thread. but if i try to change something on the ui i get an error that only the mainthread can change the ui. so i think it is running in a port of the bluetooth thread. but ill post some code

Comment: part of the bluetooth Thread that calls the callback

while (run) {
                try {

                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    if (connection.btCallback != null)
                    {
                            connection.btCallback.getData(buffer,bytes);
                    }
             
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    break;
                }

the callback methode of the bluetooth thread:

public void getData(byte[] bytes, int len)
     {
        setTacho(); 
     }

Comment: can you add that code to your question too in which you are running this function in a bluetooth thread. Its hard to read it through comments :)

Comment: ah ok now i found the edit button xD much nicer then this comments ;)

Comment: whats **ivNadel**, **ivLoad** and **ivBoost**?

Comment: sorry for answering so late but i wasn't at my pc during the weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your rotations code in a separate thread, so you may set the animation to your ImageViews as below:

```
//for example
ivNadel.post(new Runnable() {   
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ivNadel.setAnimation(RpmAnim);
    }
});
```

see if it helps for you

Comment: damn didn't help. still slow =(

Comment: well i finally made it. i changed the rotateanimations a matrix.postrotate. now it works better